# Creating a new pandas data frame with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, iteration

I have a pandas data frame of stock prices also including a date.
Now I tried to create a new data frame only including the values of a specific day per month and if this day is not existing to use another one with an if and elif condition.

I used following code but I receive the error of:
"ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
for i in month:
    if df[df['month']==i] and df[df['day']==5]:
        new_df=df.series
    elif df[df['month']==i] and df[df['day']==6]:
        new_df=df.series
```

Do you know how to solve this?
Thanks for your help already.

Best regards,
Marvin

Comment: Please add an example and detail on the problem, not clear enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using this data :

```
    month   day
0   1       5
1   1       6
2   3       5
3   4       5
4   5       6
```

Then all you have to do :

```
temp_df = df.loc[df["day"].isin([5, 6])]
temp_df = temp_df.drop_duplicates(["month"], keep="first")
temp_df

    month   day
0   1       5
2   3       5
3   4       5  
4   5       6
```

If your data is not sorted, you can always use **df.sort_values** so this would work.